# JSON Serialization in C# - Object in Object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is there possible to display all element from "UserStatus" direct in json.

From:
{ "UserName": "test", "UserStatus" { "Id" : "1", "Status" "status" }}

To:
{ "UserName": "test", "Id" : "1", "Status" "status" }

```
public class UserStatus 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }
}
    
public class User 
{
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
}

var user = new User();  

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
```

Comment: You can always create a flattened DTO and map properties to it.

Comment: You can use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) library for these kind of projections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var user = new User() { UserName = "userName", Status = new UserStatus {Id=1,Status="status"}};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
                                                  UserName=user.UserName,
                                                  Id=user.Status.Id,
                                                  Status=user.Status.Status
                                               });
```

output

```
{"UserName":"userName","Id":1,"Status":"status"}
```